# Is a linear random walk with jump recurrent?

Tags: stochastic-processes, recursion, random-walk, poisson-distribution

Let $\lambda_0=10^5$ or any other large integer. Define the recursive "process": $\lambda_t=\text{sample from a Poisson distribution with mean }\lambda_{t-1}$. Is this process recurrent? I mean, after a long time, does the probability of reaching "the other side" of the initial mean have a non-zero lower bound? Or is the probability of reaching 0 or $\infty$ positive?

Thanks!

I did some initial experiments (t=20k, repeat for 10 times, all decreasing) finding that the mean has trend to decrease. According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), Poisson with large mean can be approximated by normal($\lambda,\lambda$). By normal approximation, I found that the occurrence of $\lambda_{20k}<10k$ is slightly more than that of $\lambda_{20k}>10k$ (12 vs 8).

Comment: Have you compiled any data on your recursive process?

Comment: What do you mean by "compile any data"? I did some simulation, finding that $\lambda_t$ has decreasing trend.

Comment: That is what I mean.  Perhaps you could share some of the data you have observed and how you obtained it so it would be possible to give an informed answer to your question.

Comment: The probability of reaching 0 is 1. A simple approach to show this is to compute recursively the generating function $E(s^{\lambda_t})$ and to show that $E(s^{\lambda_t})\to1$ for every $s$ in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Did, Is it because 0 is an absorbing state? Can you please explain the generating function in detail? I'm not familiar with this form of g.f. Why can the mean appear in the generating function? How can this form fit to $E[e^{sk}]$?